# Не работает страница сайта на мобильном Android браузер Opera mini ver. 47

Tags: opera

Всем привет!

Есть страница сайта https://creditkasa.ua/new/newclient
На телефоне android, браузер Opera mini не открывает страницу **без режима** "Экономии трафика".

Режим "Экономии трафика" имеет 3 вариации.

Вариация "автоматический" - работает.
Вариация "экстремальный" - работает. 
Вариация "Высокий"- не открывает.
От блокировки рекламы не зависит.

На всех остальных браузерах все работает.

Подскажите кто сталкивался со схожей проблемой, как ее возможно решить? И в чем вариации  "автоматический" и "экстремальный" отличаются от вариации "Высокий"? Спасибо огромное!

Comment: У меня открывает во всех трёх вариациях.

Comment: С обычной мобильной Оперы открывает, но с Опера мини нет

Comment: Как я уже говорил, у меня с оперы мини открывает во всех трёх вариациях.